# Is there a way to customise Java's setEnabled(false)?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Let's say you have a `JCheckBox` you want to use as an on/off indicator. You use `setEnabled(false)` to disable mouse clicks on the `JCheckBox`. But `setEnabled(false)` also grays out the checkBox and the checkBox's text. Is there a way to customise `setEnabled(false)` so that the graying out does not happen?

If that's not possible, is the only solution something along the lines of customising a `ButtonModel`?

Comment: if you want that for all your checkboxes, change the Look and Feel. TO disable mouse clicks, you can also add a transparent component above it (you should also disable receiving focus or the user could use the keyboard for checking it).

Comment: This is a common issue with UI frameworks. The disabled (read-only) state is not very readable. I'm interested in what others do to address this.

Comment: Use a different UI element, possibly a JLabel with changing text, or something else. Check boxes are "reserved elements" in usability terms. Using a checkbox as an indicator that can't be used to change the setting is analogous to using #define to make C look like a different language. Sure, it's legal, but why would you ever cause users to go through that pain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass JCheckBox and override processMouseEvent/processKeyEvent to not do anything.

```
public class ReadOnlyCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
    public ReadOnlyCheckBox (String text, boolean selected) {
        super(text,selected);
    }

    protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending the `JCheckBox` would let you override the `setEnabled` method, and pass your `CustomJCheckBox` to any code expecting a `JCheckBox` as a parameter. That should keep you from having to reimplement everything else from the check box, as you would for implementing a ButtonModel.

I am a little confused at what you're using the check box for -- it's not enabled, but you still want a check to appear or not, based on some other parameter? Why use an input element, in that case?

Comment: To clear up the confusion - JCheckBox's appearance is useful and clear for indicating whether a setting has been set or not. Yes it is an input element but the idea is to disable input.

Comment: I feel as though you might run into issues with user confusion by not clearly indicating this checkbox won't respond to clicks. Any reason you can't use some sort of enabled/disabled icon, instead?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the colour of text in a disabled JCheckbox has been requested and is still an open issue in the Sun Bug Database:

[[6289684] Way to change the color of disabled JCheckbox text](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6289684)

Take a look at the bug details for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You customize [Button UI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html) to do this.